# Window.localStorage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Whenever the "save" button is clicked, the values of the input elements are saved in the local storage so that when the page is reloaded, the "states of the page" can be restored (including values of the input elements, the image of the selected animal, the values in `<div id="title">` and `<div id="description">`.

I tried the way in the W3School, but somehow it did not work. The page will refresh after reloading.

The html is shown below:

```
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <div>
    <input name="title" id="title1"  placeholder="Title ..." value="">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="fruit">Animal choice: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="wolf" checked> Wolf
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="lemur"> Lemur
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="cat"> Cat
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="raccoon"> Raccoon
  </div>

  <div>
    <textarea name="description" rows="6" cols="60" value=""
      placeholder="Description ..."></textarea>
  </div>


</form>
<div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<hr>

<div>
  <h3 id=t1>Title ...</h3>
  <div><img id=animal_img src="img/wolf.jpg" alt="wolf"></div>
  <div id=description>Description ...</div>

  </div>

  <div id="result">...</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I already edited my question adding the HTML code.

Comment: You should post the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a listener to check if the radio is changed and then use an `if` to check the value and then define the image, description, etc...
Here I used a very basic and general jQuery selector `input[type='radio']`, you can use a class to be more specific if you want.

There's a function called `AdjustSelected`, it makes all adjustments, changing image, title, etc... you can call it when the page loads, passing the value that comes from the localStorage, to adjust everything right n the loading of the page.

```js
AdjustSelected = function(valSelected){  
  if (valSelected == 'wolf'){
    $('#t1').text('The Wolf');
    $('#animal_img').attr('src', 'PATH_TO_IMAGE');   
    $('#animal_img').attr('alt', 'wolf');
    $('#description').text('TEXT_YOU_WANT');
    
  }else if (valSelected == 'lemur'){
    $('#t1').text('The Lemur');
    $('#animal_img').attr('src', 'PATH_TO_IMAGE');
    $('#animal_img').attr('alt', 'lemur');
    $('#description').text('TEXT_YOU_WANT');
    
  }else if (valSelected == 'cat'){
    $('#t1').text('The Cat');
    $('#animal_img').attr('src', 'PATH_TO_IMAGE');
    $('#animal_img').attr('alt', 'cat');
    $('#description').text('TEXT_YOU_WANT');
    
  }else if (valSelected == 'raccoon'){
    $('#t1').text('The Raccoon');
    $('#animal_img').attr('src', 'PATH_TO_IMAGE');
    $('#animal_img').attr('alt', 'raccoon');
    $('#description').text('TEXT_YOU_WANT');    
  }
};

$("input[type='radio']").on('change', function(){
  var valSelected = this.value;
  AdjustSelected(valSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="title" id="title1"  placeholder="Title ..." value=""/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="animal" id='radioAnimals'>Animal choice: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="wolf" checked> Wolf
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="lemur"> Lemur
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="cat"> Cat
    <input type="radio" name="animal" value="raccoon"> Raccoon
  </div>

  <div>
    <textarea name="description" rows="6" cols="60" value=""
      placeholder="Description ..."></textarea>
  </div>


</form>
<div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<hr>

<div>
  <h3 id=t1>Title ...</h3>
  <div><img id=animal_img src="img/wolf.jpg" alt="wolf"></div>
  <div id=description>Description ...</div>

  </div>

  <div id="result">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend defining the data sets at the top like so:

```json
animals = { 
        wolf: { 
            title: 'The Wolf', 
            src: 'path_to_wolf_image', 
            desc: 'wolf description' 
        }, 
        lemur: { 
            title: 'The Lemur', 
            src: 'path_to_lemur_image', 
            desc: 'lemur desc' 
        }
    };
```

and then you can assign everything in one assignment block:

```js
$("input[name='animal']").change(function(){
        var animal = animals[this.value];
        if (animal != undefined) {
            $('#title1').text(animal.title);
            $('#animal_img').attr('src', animal.src);   
            $('#animal_img').attr('alt', animal.title);
            $('#description').text(animal.desc);
        }
    });
```